# Is there any `itemgetter` equivalent for `numpy.ndarray`?

Tags: python, numpy

When I call `itemgetter` with a `numpy.ndarray`, I get a `tuple`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                    
In [2]: import operator as op                                                 
In [3]: ar = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])                                            
In [4]: op.itemgetter(1,3)(ar)                                                
Out[4]: (2, 4)
```

I wonder if there's any numpy function that's like `itemgetter` but returns an `ndarray` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With numpy arrays you can access multiple indices directly by indexing into the array with a list:

```
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> x[[1, 3]]
array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 3):

Might not be answering the question, but I'd do something like

```
ar[[1,3]]
```

to get back a numpy.ndarray object with the required elements